# sql query of not filling table entry

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Write a query to display the name and role details of all users who have filled in the profile details, sorted by name in ascending order. for this question my query is as follows:

```
select name,
role.name,
role.id 
    from user,role 
where user.profile_id= profile.id 
AND profile_id IN (select id from profile where address IS NOT NULL AND batch IS NOT NULL AND degree_id IS NOT NULL AND designation IS NOT NULL AND gender IS NOT NULL) order by name asc
```

but this query is not working,please suggest some way to correct my query for question

Comment: Use of both MYSQL and SQL-SERVER tags is unusual.  Which platform is it?

Comment: when you are joining with role where the profile table comes

Comment: Can you elaborate on "this query is not working"? Are you getting an error? Different results than what you what? If so, how do they differ?

Comment: You have a typo, which may be the issue. `user.profile_id = profile.id`. You may want `user.profile_id = role.profile_id`, but now I see you have a table called profile so I don't know what the relationship is.

Comment: Also, please use explicit join syntax. they are a part of ansi-sql for over 20 years now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, or provide extra information about your schema as it is hard to create queries blindly.

```
SELECT 
     user.Name, role.Name, role.Id
FROM 
   user u
   INNER JOIN Role r ON u.role_id = r.Id
   INNER JOIN Profie p ON u.profile_Id = p.profile_id
WHERE 
   address IS NOT NULL AND batch IS NOT NULL AND degree_id IS NOT NULL 
   AND designation IS NOT NULL AND gender IS NOT NULL
```

The main problem is that you trying to join with role without actually joining to the table.

I have made up the join between User and Role as your question didn't show the relationship. Tweak as necessary.

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the problem is in the join, and providing an example, however your where clause has a typo as it starts with `WHERE AND`